# Joining two tables on based on second number value from first table

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, join

I am new to SQL, so please bear with me.

I am working with two tables that do not have common fields. I am trying to create simple hierarchy based on the two tables that look like this:

```
   Table 1. 

Cul 1   Cul 2 
============== 
S10000  Name 
S20000  Name 1 
S30000  Name 2 
S40000  Name 3

 Table 2 

Cul 1   Cul 2  
=====================
A10000  Test 
A10001  Test 123 
A20000  Test 1
A20001  Test 999 
A30000  Test 2  
A30002  Test 5555 
A40000  Test 3   
A40006  Test 84384848
```

I would like to write a query that will display ‘Name’ field from Table 1 based on matching numeric values in the first columns from table 1 & 2.

So if Table 1 is S10000, display A1000 – Test

Is that possible?

Thank you

Comment: when you say "based on matching numeric values in the first columns from table 1 & 2", how can you expect to do that when non of the numbers match?  Even in your example result, S10000 and A1000 are off by one 0.

Comment: I didn't know that matter but characters in table 1&2 are the same length. I just made the adjustment.

Comment: @Zhenya what RDBMS are you using? SQL Server, mysql, oracle?

Comment: Is there always a single non-numeric character before the matching #s?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
SELECT
   t2.*
FROM Table1 t1
INNER JOIN Table2 t2 on SUBSTRING(t1.Cul1,2,LEN(t1.Cul1)-1)=SUBSTRING(t2.Cul1,2,LEN(t2.Cul1)-1)
```

Comment: I just checked and not all values are getting picked up. The code skips over some values from some reason.

Comment: For example, table 2 values that start with a A3 or A4 are ignored.

Comment: Please ignore my comment. i had values in reverse order

Answer (score 5):

Your requirements are not exactly clear but it sounds like you want this:

```
select t1.col1 t1Name,
  t1.col2 t1Value,
  t2.col1 t2Name,
  t2.col2 t2Value
from table1 t1
inner join table2 t2
  on substring(t1.col1, 2, 1) = substring(t2.col1, 2, 1)
```

## see [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/9247a/3)

edit, you can also use:

```
select t1.col1 t1Name,
  t1.col2 t1Value,
  t2.col1 t2Name,
  t2.col2 t2Value
from table1 t1
inner join table2 t2
  on substring(t1.col1, 2, len(t1.col1)) 
      = substring(t2.col1, 2, len(t2.col1));
```

Comment: Another issue with the query, values are doubling. So instead of returning single description for combination of the two tables. I am seeing multiple values.

Comment: can you explain what you mean?

Comment: In table 1 i only have 7 rows, and that's all i should end up with after i combine the two tables. Where in my join tables i have 15 different values, some are duplicating. For example - S10000  Name shows up 4 times, instead of only once.

Comment: @Zhenya your requirements are not very clear, but you can also use the query I just provided in my edit

Comment: @Zhenya see this sql fiddle -- http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/9247a/10  -- they are aliases

Answer (score 0):

If you are very sure that the first digit will be the digit and followed by the numeric then the below should work

```
SELECT A.cul1,B.cul2 
FROM dbo.Table1 A, dbo.Table2 B
WHERE substring(A.cul1,2,len(A.cul1))= substring(B.cul1,2,len(B.cul1))
```